# Rewrite rule to add index.shtml

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to write a rewrite rule such that if the address "www.example1.test.com" is entered in the URL it will append index.shtml to the end and go to that instead - "www.examples1.test.com/index.shtml"

I have tried both of the following below but neither work:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^www.example1.test.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1/index.shtml [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.test.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1/index.shtml [R,L]

Can anyone advise what im doing wrong please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre going a bit overkill to get the default page working.

Find this line.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

and change it as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html
```